# nested array to object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

convert to object

```js
[1, 2, [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, [9, 0], 11, 12]
```

Output want

```js
{
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  'array1': {
    4: 4,
    5: 5,
    6: 6
  },
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  'array2': {
    9: 9,
    0: 0
  },
  11: 11,
  12: 12
}
```

but output get {
1: 1,
11: 11,
12: 12,
2: 2,
7: 7,
8: 8
}

my code

```js
input = [1,2,[4,5,6],7,8,[9,0],11,12];
obj = {}

const convert = (arr) =>{
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(!Array.isArray(arr[i])){
        obj[arr[i]] = arr[i];
    }
    
 }}
    convert(input);
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Yeah, an `else` case right there would be appropriate to do the rest. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Convert Using For Each

```js
input = [1, 2, [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, [9, 0], 11, 12];
obj = {}
const convertUsingForEach = (arr) => {
    let arrCount = 0;
    arr.forEach(i => {
        if (Array.isArray(i)) {
            arrCount++;
            i.forEach(j => {
                if (!obj[`array${arrCount}`]) {
                    obj[`array${arrCount}`] = {};
                }
                obj[`array${arrCount}`][j] = j;
            });
        } else {
            obj[i] = i;
        }
    })
}
convertUsingForEach(input);
console.log(obj);
```

Convert Using Reduce

```js
const input = [1, 2, [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, [9, 0], 11, 12];
let obj = {}
const convertUsingReduce = (arr) => {
    let arrCount = 0;
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
        if (Array.isArray(b)) {
            a[`array${++arrCount}`] = convertUsingReduce(b);
        } else {
            a[b] = b;
        };
        return a;
    }, {})
};
obj = convertUsingReduce(input);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it:

```js
const input = [1,2,[4,5,6],7,8,[9,0],11,12];

const convert = arr=>{
  let n=0;
  return arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
    if (Array.isArray(c)) a["array"+(++n)]=convert(c);
    else                  a[c]=c;
    return a}, {})
 }
 console.log( convert(input) );
```